# REST Design Pattern 1 endpoint, different object return types

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to determine the best approach for returning different objects from 1 REST endpoint.

**Example:**

Suppose the client has a Customer ID: 123 and calls `GET /api/customers/123`

- The consuming client has no other knowledge of the customer, other than the ID
- The customer returned can either be and Individual or a Business, each with their own unique properties. Each of these objects can be updated

My current design has multiple PUT endpoints to support the unique updates

1. `PUT /api/businesses/123`
2. `PUT /api/customers/123`

The problem I see is the client now has to call another endpoint to perform the update on the Business customer which makes the API more complicated to consume and I'm not sure its best practice to return different object types from 1 GET endpoint.

Are there any alternatives or does this approach seem reasonable?

**EDIT:** So I think my problem is more due to the fact that I'm treating these entities are truly unique when in fact, they are the same (barring some meta data properties). @Patrick Hofman and @LB2 for your answers. I will refactor

Comment: I don't see the REST API layer getting more complicated just because you add an endpoint! Clearly you just need some documentation put in place...

Comment: How do the two endpoints relate to each other?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The only way to retrieve Individual or Business info is via the single GET. There is no relation between the PUT requests as they are updating separate entities.

Comment: So what is the relation to them in the GET?

Comment: @PatrickHofman They are both of the same base type, customer. They do share some properties but most are unique. For instance, if i were to change an Individuals name, it would be First Name and Last Name, but a  Business is their Operating Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) as means of directing client where respective relevant resources are.

The model that backs the `GET` call would pretty much be combining data properties of both models - whether that's a good idea or not really depends on how disparate are your `Business` and `Customer` models.  If justified to be close to similar with minor differences, then perhaps combining is reasonable.

For each type however, you would generate the proper link for `PUT`, directing the client as to where to do the update.  What to send for update would depends on contract between your service and your client.

Comment: I have implemented HATEOS links for the entities respective PUT endpoints and I like that the API becomes "self discoverable". I do like the idea of combining both models as it would eliminate the complex mapping i have currently (CustomerBaseModel -- > (IndividualModel, BusinessModel)).